# SQL - REGEX Match the whole word if it has an @ symbol in it

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I am using Snowflake and specifically the REGEXP_REPLACE function. I am looking for a Regex expression that will match any word with an @ symbol in it in a text field.

Example:

| RAW_DATA | CLEANED_DATA |
| --- | --- |
| here is a sample and then an email@gmail.com | here is a sample and then an xxxxx |
| abc@test.com | xxxxx |

What I have tried so far is:

```
Select regexp_replace('ABC@gmail.com' , '(([a-zA-Z]+)(\W)?([a-zA-Z]+))', 'xxxxxxx') as result;
```

Result:

```
xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sql
Select regexp_replace('here is a sample and then an email@gmail.com' , '\\S+@\\S+', 'xxxxx') as result;
```

Here,

- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `@` - a `@` char
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars